# PHP Code Style Fixer: put space between colon and method's return type

Tags: php, coding-style

Is there a [PHP CS Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) fixer available that will put space between colon and return type? Fixer should correct this signature:

```
public function modifyFeatureFlags(array $feature_flags):array
{
}
```

to:

```
public function modifyFeatureFlags(array $feature_flags): array
{
}
```

The list of available fixers is long, and I have hard time finding the correct one.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Problem is described, when you are familiar with the particular piece of the software. Here's an example of CS Fixer configuration: https://github.com/activecollab/authentication/blob/master/.php_cs.php My question is regarding a particular fixer, that may be a recent development, or may not even exist (that I tried to find). Question looks pretty on-topic to me ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [README.md](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/master/README.rst)

> **return_type_declaration** [@Symfony]
>
> There should be one or no space before colon and one space after it in return
>   type declaration.

[Try it out](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:2.16|fixer:return_type_declaration)

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @keradus, there is **return_type_declaration** for that.

If you (or anyone else) would like to use **a sniff for PHP_CodeSniffer**, there is [ReturnTypeHintSpacingSniff](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard/blob/master/SlevomatCodingStandard/Sniffs/TypeHints/ReturnTypeHintSpacingSniff.php) from [slevomat/coding-standard](https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard).